# Crystal Reports, 'The report you requested requires further information' is working fine in development, not working in testing server

Tags: report

I have a problem with Crystal Reports, the reports are working fine in the development environment, but, when executing the application in the test server I get this prompt from the CrystalViewer:

```
Server name:  *Here's the absolute path of the report in the development server*
Database name: *Correctly filled*
User name:  *Correctly filled* 
Password: *Empty*
```

This is the code that I'm using to pass the login information to the report:

```
Try
        rptDoc = New ReportDocument
        rptPath = Server.MapPath(rutaReporte)
        Dim conInfo As New ConnectionInfo
        conInfo.ServerName = Server.MapPath("~/reportes.dsn")
        conInfo.DatabaseName = "database"
        conInfo.UserID = "reportUser"
        conInfo.Password = "password"
        rptDoc.Load(rptPath)
        setInicioReportes(conInfo, rptDoc)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptPath
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Show error message
    End Try
```

I don't understand why the CrystalReport isn't recognizing the DSN file that I have specified  in code. And in the DNS file I have saved the password, user_id, server and database, which, as I said before, is working  in development environment.

If someone knows how to solve this, it will be really helpful.

Thanks to everyone.

EDIT: Also, when I enter the password in the prompt try to Log In the page just refreshes and nothing happens, the prompt pops again.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, in your solution explorer, you will need to click on references, then CrystalReports.Shared, and then set the properties as shown:

[image: CopyLocal True]

Set Embed Interop Types to False and the Copy Local to True.

CrystalDecisions.Shared is where your connection class definitions are stored for CrystalReports.  Without a Visual Studio environment (or this library nearby) on your server, this is likely why you are getting your error.

Re-Build your solution and put the new executable on your server and it should work!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have checked what you suggested but it doesn't seem to solve the problem, I realized  that  is only the reports to which I'm passing parameters through code that are giving me this error, do you think it has something to do with the way I'm passing the parameters?

Comment: The parameters look fine to me, and the fact that it works on the development computer and not on the server indicates that there is something that is not on the server that is causing your program to crash.  I can think of a couple of things to check:  1.  Is the ODBC DSN you have set up on your development computer identical to one you have set up on the server?  2.  Have you tried setting Copy Local to true on all of the Crystal references you are using?  3.  Does the server have .NET installed (Check C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET )  4.  Are you building the solution as Release (and not Debug)?